# Display dynamic frequencies on axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I've got a list of frequencies, all in the same unit (Hz, MHz, etc.), how can I use a scale to display them nicely on the x-axis?  I want them to be labeled Hz/kHz/MHz and scaled appropriately.

Comment: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis

Comment: @rioV8 I've read the documentation, it doesn't seem to support automatic labeling of frequencies like it does time.  I want behavior similar to when you use a time scale and d3 will automatically switch between days/months/years depending on the domain, except I just need it to switch between Hz/kHz/Mhz.  If I have to write my own logic for making the labels I'm just not going to bother with d3.

Comment: write a custom tick formatter https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually want is simply a number with a [SI prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) followed by `Hz` as the unit of measurement.

That being said, you can use a linear scale and a specific `tickFormat`:

```
const format = d3.format(".0s");

axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
    return format(d) + "Hz";
});
```

Where `axis` is your axis generator, whatever it is. Here, `".0s"` in the specifier formats the number to use SI prefixes and no decimal places. Then, you get the resulting string and add `"Hz"` to it.

Here is a demo, the domain changes continually between `[0, 1]` and `[0, 100000000000]`:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 1000])
  .range([30, 470]);

const format = d3.format(".0s");

const axis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    return format(d) + "Hz";
  });

const g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)");

g.call(axis);

d3.interval(function() {
  scale.domain([0, Math.pow(10, ~~(Math.random() * 12))]);
  g.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .call(axis)
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks!  Wasn't familiar with d3.format, the SI prefix is a big help.